# Javascript "return this" meet the "return"?

Tags: javascript, return

```
var Person = function(){};


function klass() {
     initialize = function(name) {
          // Protected variables
          var _myProtectedMember = 'just a test';

          this.getProtectedMember = function() {
             return _myProtectedMember;
          }

          this.name = name;
              return this;
       };
     say = function (message) {                
          return this.name + ': ' + message + this.getProtectedMember();
          // how to use "return this" in here,in order to mark the code no error.
       };
//console.log(this);   

return {
               constructor:klass,
        initialize : initialize,
        say: say
    } 
    //return this;
}

Person.prototype = new klass();
//console.log(Person.prototype);
new Person().initialize("I :").say("you ").say(" & he");
```

how to use "return this" in "say",in order to mark the code no error.

i want to know that how to 'Chain call'  in the function which has return alrealy?

Comment: Your function can return either the response message or the object itself to allow chaining. It can not return both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need return a class instance to chain call. I would suggest you create a base class for all your objects that is able to store the outputs of the class, and will return it in the "toString" or similar function, maybe "output".

Your code then becomes:

```
(new Person()).initialize("I :").say("you ").say(" & he").toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Only one object can be returned.

So you have two options.

One - Show the message inside the function ans return `this`

```
say = function (message) {                
    // show the message here e.g. using an alert    
    alert(this.name + ': ' + message + this.getProtectedMember());
    // then return instance
    return this;
};
```

Two - Return an object containing instance and message

```
say = function (message) {  
    message =  this.name + ': ' + message + this.getProtectedMember();            
    return {message:message, instance:this};
};
```

and call it like

```
new Person().initialize("I :").say("you ").instance.say(" & he");
```